# how do i install ubuntu on macbook 10.7.5

Tags: system-installation

How do you install Ubuntu on a Macbook 10.7.5, and which which version should be used?  I've tried the latest version, 16.04.2 and it says there is "no mountable file system".

Answer (score 1):

There are several steps to installing ubuntu. You can find them on the web, but I'll also list them out for you :)

Ubuntu 16.04 will work fine

## Partition your drive

When you boot into ubuntu through your bootable medium, select the "try ubuntu" option, not the "install ubuntu" option. Now you can use ubuntu. Open gparted and partition your hard drive. Make a new partition with an ext4 file system. If you don't know how, check out this guide:

https://www.lifewire.com/do-you-need-home-partition-2202048

Alternatively, you can partition your hard drive from the installation menu, just make sure to select the "something else" option.

## Install Ubuntu

Now your hard drive is partitioned for installing ubuntu. Follow the instructions and when you get to the "Installation Type" menu, select the "Install Ubuntu Alongside Another OS" option.

Now, you follow the rest of the instructions and wait for ubuntu to install!

Hope this helps to you!

P.S.

If you want more detail, check this out:

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop